# "a time when you or a relative were/was a patient"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, disjunction, grammatical-person

Is the following sentence correct?

1. > Don't be afraid to talk about a time when you or a relative **were** a patient.

Or should it be one of the following:

2. > Don't be afraid to talk about a time you or a relative **was** a patient.
3. > Don't be afraid to talk about a time when you **were** or a relative **was** a patient.

Comment: Related: [Is it right to use a singular form of the verb in this sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230099)

Comment: When two subjects are joined by the conjunction **or**, the verb should agree with the nearer one.  Example: "Don't be afraid to talk about a time when you or **a relative was** a patient". Or, "Don't be afraid to talk about a time when  a relative or **you were** a patient".

Answer (score 0):

Surely this has already been addressed, but [the general rule is to make the verb agree with the nearer term of the disjunction](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/01/).

That said, all of these sentences are terribly awkward and it's better to just rephrase it to avoid the problem.

> Don't be afraid to talk about your own hospitalization or that of a relative.
>
> Don't be afraid to share your own experiences as a patient or as one's relative.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't parse "your own experiences as a patient or as one's relative" properly.

Comment: I'll retract my ill-considered comment of a few seconds ago.

Comment: Surely the 'general rule' is therefore 'It's better to just rephrase it to avoid the problem.'

Comment: Thanks all. Hospitalization is different from being a patient, but I get the gist. Thanks!